# Appending PostScript files

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I have been looking into appending PostScript files and tools available to do so.  One option that seems commonly used is GhostScript.  I was able to get this to append files together however in the process I lost the /MediaPosition settings that were in my original files.  Eventually may combined file will be sent to a printer and the tray selection is important.  Is Ghostscript capalbe of preserving this information during the append process?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably 'append' PostScript files, because PostScript is a programming language and you can't simply stick two programs together and expect them to work. Sometimes you'll be lucky and it will work, sometimes it won't, or won't behave the way you expect.

If you are using Ghostscript to do something you definitely are **not** 'appending' PostScript programs.

I assume you are using the ps2write output device and sending multiple input files, in order to get a new output program. No, ps2write absolutely will not preserve device-specific information such as tray position. For the reasons why, see the documentation [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.50/VectorDevices.htm#Overview)

You can use the PSDocOptions and PSPageOptions to insert device-specific code into the output of the ps2write device, see section 6.5 of the documentation page linked above